# if stament always returns false

Tags: cocoa, if-statement, applescript

I'm unable to get this function to work. The if always return false. What i'm doing wrong?
This come from a cocoa checkbox, the OverrideBuildCheked is 1 when checked and 0 when unchecked.

```
on OverRideBuildNumber_(sender)

    set OverrideBuildCheked to CurrentBuildOverrideChk's state

    if OverrideBuildCheked = 1 then
        CurrentBuildField's setEnabled_(true)
        CurrentBuildField's setEditable_(false)
    else
        CurrentBuildField's setEnabled_(false)
        CurrentBuildField's setEditable_(true)
    end if
end OverRideBuildNumber_
```

Comment: Haven't done this in a while, but looking at my previous code : `set OverrideBuildCheked to CurrentBuildOverrideChk's intValue()`. Is your ckeckbox's outlet referenced correctly to `CurrentBuildOverrideChk`

Comment: If `CurrentBuildField` is an outlet, make sure it's hooked up in the nib and that you have loaded that nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about everything from Cocoa is a pointer to an object (you can see this by logging the result), so you usually need to coerce to the desired AppleScript class, e.g. **CurrentBuildOverrideChk's state as integer** (or **boolean**).